# Stacking Divs When Resizing Browser

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to html/css and am running into an issue where my divs are overlapping when I shrink the browser and the gap between the two divs gets larger as I expand. I am wondering how to just have a fixed margin of about 20px between each. These are both inside of a parent div

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cro7mjsh/2/

```
<div class="main-outer">
<div class="about-inner">
<h3>「 About 」</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
  dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</p>
</div>

<div class="clients-inner">
<h3>「 Clients 」</h3>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="1" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="2" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="3" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="4" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="./Assets/Clients/logo.jpg" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code for us, or else it will be a wild guess on our part.

Comment: You're absolutely positioning and centering some elements in arbitrarily sized space (overall height of `800px` and `margin-top` of second element of `275px` - which leaves a `275px` height in which the first element is visible). It should be obvious that won't behave nicely when you want to narrow your screen - which should result in an increase of their heights. Your centering technique is utterly flawed and non-responsive. There are ways to do it responsively, but some research is required on your part first. The first thing to drop is `position:absolute`, btw.

Comment: Code and Fiddle are attached

Comment: In essence, `position:absolute` means: tell the parent to behave like I'm not here. If you want the parent to behave like the child ***is there***, don't use `position:absolute;` on the child.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/2sp5omh6/) is probably closer to what you're after.

Comment: @Andrei Sorry - I should have added the hero section as well (updated on fiddle). Removing position:absolute; from both child divs takes them away from being centered. And I am aware of how flawed it is which is why I'm reaching out for help. I am self-teaching for fun and learned the centering technique from reading threads on here.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Andrei, I will give that a try

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need flex to make this work.

Remove flex from "main-outer".

Remove absolute from about-inner and clients-inner. Add "margin: 20px auto 0px auto" to each of these as well to get your desired effect.

View my recommended solve on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/matie/pen/jdyNNQ).

Best of luck!

```
.main-outer {
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.about-inner {
  border:1px blue solid !important;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  clear:both;
}

.clients-inner {
  border:1px blue solid !important;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: You seem inconsistent. You say: you don't need flex for this, but your pen still uses flex.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I meant, you don't need flex for the divs I mentioned. I should not rush and type. Go ahead and recommend a better solution.

Comment: Sorry for rushing. If I said, for example. *"I don't think you need flex to make this work."*, what is it that you, personally, would have understood I'm saying? Take your time.